# How to use EJB in testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I don't have any idea about EJB. 
what I want to know:
that how `EJB`can use in testing?
If you know that, please give me an example

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/1.0.0.Alpha1/en-US/html_single/#examples.ejb

Here's a JUnit Arquillian test that validates the behavior of the EJB session bean GreetingManager. Arquillian looks up an instance of the EJB session bean in the test archive and injects it into the matching field type annotated with @EJB.

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import org.jboss.arquillian.api.Deployment;

import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;

import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archives;

import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;

import org.junit.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)

public class InjectionTestCase {

@Deployment

public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {

```
  return Archives.create("test.jar", JavaArchive.class)

     .addClasses(GreetingManager.class, GreetingManagerBean.class);
```

}

@EJB

private GreetingManager greetingManager;

@Test

public void shouldBeAbleToInjectEJB() throws Exception {

```
  String userName = "Earthlings";

  Assert.assertEquals(Hello " + userName, greetingManager.greet(userName));
```

}

}